# pivot_longer for multiple groups of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a following `data.frame`:

```
structure(list(id = 1:3, class_1 = c(333105L, 241306L, 242309L
), class_2 = c(333190L, 241390L, 242390L), prob_1 = c(0.954687457602604, 
0.929992569797772, 0.89535783792201), prob_2 = c(0.0335731906988228, 
0.0573986241136788, 0.096986046671658)), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to reshape my `data.frame` to
"wide" format. I want to gather cols `class_1` and `class_2` into new column `class`. Same for `prob_[0-9]` columns, so that class_1 for id 1 coresponds to prob_1, as well as class_2 for id 1 coresponds to prob_2. Same for other "IDs".

The desired outcome:

| id | class | prob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 333105 | 0.954687457602604 |
| 1 | 333190 | 0.0335731906988228 |
| 2 | 241306 | 0.929992569797772 |
| 2 | 241390 | 0.0573986241136788 |
| 3 | 242309 | 0.89535783792201 |
| 3 | 242390 | 0.096986046671658 |

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(matches("[[:digit:]]$", perl = T), names_to = "class", values_to = "val") %>%
```

Gathers both `class` and `prob` into single column, while:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("class"), names_to = "class", values_to = "val_class") %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("prob"), names_to = "prob", values_to = "val_prob")
```

also returns the wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the `names_to` as `.value` and then capture the names before the `_` in `names_pattern`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -id, names_to = ".value", names_pattern = "^([^_]+)_.*")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     id  class   prob
  <int>  <int>  <dbl>
1     1 333105 0.955 
2     1 333190 0.0336
3     2 241306 0.930 
4     2 241390 0.0574
5     3 242309 0.895 
6     3 242390 0.0970
```